# MySQL Query to Oracle SQL

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

```
SELECT r1.rnr, r1.anaam
FROM regisseur r1, regisseur r2
WHERE r2.anaam = <'input last name director'>
AND r1.gdatum < r2.gbdatum
```

can someone change this to an Oracle SQL query really having difficulty with it, and it shouldnt be this hard.

Comment: What difficulties are you having? Are you getting errors? If so, what errors? Are you actually including the `<>` in `<'input last name director'>` ?

Comment: this is a running query and it works as far as i have been told, but i have to make a pl/sql query which does exactly the same but needs to look completely different

Comment: *"but needs to look completely different"* - why? Did someone *tell* you it needs to look completely different? Also, this query as it stands (including the `<>` in `<'input last name director'>`) will not run in **any** version of SQL (including MySQL).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the original query does not compile, so it is a bogus exercise to convert it to some other format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the `<` and `>` characters:

```
SELECT r1.rnr, r1.anaam
FROM regisseur r1, regisseur r2
WHERE r2.anaam = 'input last name director'
AND r1.gdatum < r2.gbdatum
```

Here's [a working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eba71/1) on SQLFiddle.

---

Presuming you don't have a good reason to `SELECT` from `regisseur` twice, this can be further condensed down to:

```
SELECT rnr, anaam
FROM regisseur
WHERE anaam = 'input last name director'
AND gdatum < gbdatum
```

Comment: tyvm that last bit helped me